# How can attribute Creative Common Attribution font to make an album cover?

Tags: fonts, licensing, font-licensing

I want to ask something since I'm not a real designer or anything. I made a music album cover and how can I attribute a font in this case, since the album cover doesn't have a description...
the font is "curvilingus" by Tup Wander

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. Why don't you email the author, and offer to pay a fee for the font so you don't have to add an attribution.  His email is included in the readme file.

Answer (score 1):

It would usually be placed on the back of the cover. If you are using it digitally though either pay a fee to author, create a custom typeface or use an open source font.
Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Normally such info would be on the back of the album sleeve..

However, with only a digital cover you don't really have many options other than to add a small line of text somewhere on the cover image. Or.. use an image that is not under an attribution license.